# Lookup values from matrix based on row data (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, lookup

I have something like the following:

```
X = [1 5; 2 5; 3 7; 4 7; 5 2; 6 7];

X =

 1     5
 2     5
 3     7
 4     7
 5     2
 6     7

b = [1;4;6];

b =

 1
 4
 6
```

Is there a way to lookup the values (from X), input as b, to output the following:

```
b1 =

 1     5
 4     7
 6     7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that the values of `b` are within the range of `X`:

```
c = X(b,:);
```

or if the first column of `X` isn't `1:N`:

```
[~,idx]=ismember(b,X(:,1));
idx(idx==0)=[];
c = X(idx,:);
```

Comment: Didn't realize it was this simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`INTERSECT`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html).

#### For the downvoter and/or people who didn't get it:

```
[~,index] = intersect(X(:,1),b)
b1 = [b X(index,2)];
```

Comment: what does this have to do with the question? I just don't see it :(